# JNI error while calling a C subroutine

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I want to call a C subroutine from Java. I'm using JNI. I have created the .java, .c, and .h files, and compiled a DLL. All the files are in the same folder. But when I run the program, it shows an `unsatisfiedlinkError`. Where am I going wrong...?

As I am learning JNI, the source code I used is the one from: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/section2.html and things I have already tried:

- Create a dll using Code::Blocks(ide) and GCC as the compiler
- Create dll using GCC from command line (Ref. http://sig9.com/node/35 )
- I am using Win7 32 bit, and I guess all the methods above generate 32-bit DLLs
- All the solutions I found for creating a DLL (shared library) are for MS VC/VCPP and I don't have that on my machine right now.

Where is the problem? DLL files are being generated without any exception, but when I run the Java code, it throws the exception.

---

PS: If there is any theoretical examples that explains how JNI works and what actually it does, then kindly share the link...

The message or exception being thrown:

```
    c:\myjava1>java Sample1
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Sample1.intMethod(I)I
      at Sample1.intMethod(Native Method)
      at Sample1.main(Sample1.java:11)
```

At the end of the day after creating dll file lots of times,I am pretty sure that there is possibly no issue with it ,something is wrong with the path ...I have changed the **loadlibrary** method with **load** method ,but still no luck,.....

---

as suggested by a MOD:
I have been discussing about this question on the post:JNI error while calling a C subroutine ,I am posting all the codes here as the comments have limited characters... Sample1.c

```
#include "jni.h"
#include"Sample_Sample1.h"
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Sample_Sample1_test(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){
return(1);
}
void main(){}
```

Sample1.java

```
package Sample;

public class Sample1
{
public native int test();
static{ 
System.loadLibrary("Sample1");
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
 Sample1 sample = new Sample1();
 System.out.println(sample.test());
 }
}
```

Sample_Sample1.h(generated using javah -jni command)

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include "jni.h"
/* Header for class Sample_Sample1 */

#ifndef _Included_Sample_Sample1
#define _Included_Sample_Sample1
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     Sample_Sample1
 * Method:    test
 * Signature: ()I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Sample_Sample1_test
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Can anyone guide me where the issue is?In earlier post I mentioned that the code I am using is the one from tutorials ,but to simplyfy the things I have changed the codes ...While using **java Sample.Sample1" i am getting:

c:\myjava1>java Sample.Sample1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Sample.Sample1.test()I
        at Sample.Sample1.test(Native Method)
        at Sample.Sample1.main(Sample1.java:12)

Comment: all the codes(.c and .java) are taken from the link mentioned in the post ,Still repeating:<http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/section2.html>

Comment: What is the error? Is it that Java can't find your library (the loadLibrary call fails), or is it that Java can't locate your methods? Do check if your DLL exports the correct names e.g. using dependency walker http://www.dependencywalker.com/.

Comment: Throws *what* exception? With what message? There's not enough information here.

Comment: yes the names being imported are the same as mentioned in .c file(and called in .java)

Comment: You'll have to post skeletal code: at least the Java package statement, loadLibrary() call and native method declaration, and the generated .h and .c files.

Comment: im reading developerwork in the url you specified and scroll down to the bottom you should be able to see troubleshoot section and the first bullet note is the same exception as you specified in your question.

Comment: i have gone through that ,but I am not able to understand what actually it tries to convey ,thats why I have posted the question.

Comment: did you put your java file in default package or any other package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You need to [have your library explicitly set on your path](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jniexamp.html#run).</strike>

It may be the case that the flags you are using there aren't quite right. Try this:

```
gcc -Wall -D_JNI_IMPLEMENTATION_ -Wl,--kill-at \
    -I[Java_HOME]/include -I[Java_HOME]/include/win32 \
    -shared -o Sample1.dll Sample1.c
```

From [MinGW GCC site](http://www.mingw.org/node/41).

Comment: @buch11, what is the full path to the .dll? And what is the value of your path environment variable when you attempt to execute your program? Remember, this is your path, and not your classpath.

Comment: path to .dll = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin\Sample1.dll" and path variable=" %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\program files\java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;c:\PHP; "

Comment: @buch11, I see. Perhaps it is not a path issue, but one of the .dll build process itself. What were the gcc flags used when you built your .dll?

Comment: the command i used in gcc was:::gcc -shared -o path/Sample1.dll path/Sample1.o:::I have checked the dll using the tool dependency walker as suggested and that also show normal behavior...

Comment: @buch11 It may be the case that the flags you are using there aren't quite right. Try this:  `gcc -Wall -D_JNI_IMPLEMENTATION_ -Wl,--kill-at -I[Java_HOME]/include -I[Java_HOME]/include/win32 -shared -o Sample1.dll Sample1.c`    [MinGW-GCC site](http://www.mingw.org/node/41)

Comment: Finally this gcc flags woked fine thaks a lot @buruzaemon

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your DLL by calling it from a stub C++ application?  Pay particular attention to the exact name (including capitalisation) of the method(s) you are calling.

The Javadoc for `UnsatisfiedLinkError` says "Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine cannot find an appropriate native-language definition of a method declared native." That probably means either that the name is misspelled or your DLL is not where the JVM is expecting to find it.

Comment: where the JVM will be expecting it?I have set the class path already

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the problem using System.load() method, System.loadLibrary() Still doesn't work for me...it keeps on giving the same exception, And the I think the issue was with the .dll   Thanks to all of you who supported and responded...

Answer (score 0):

After spending 2hrs and analysing the code. Problem is with .dll/.so compilation. Below command works for me:

> g++ -dynamiclib **HelloJni.cpp** -I /usr/include/ -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/include/ -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/include/linux/ **-shared** **-o libHelloJni.so**

or

> g++ -dynamiclib HelloJni.cpp -I /usr/include/ -I $JAVA_HOME/include/ -I $JAVA_HOME/include/linux/ -shared -o libHelloJni.so

Above command is for linux. In case of **Windows**, change

[Java_HOME]/include/linux/  --->  [Java_HOME]/include/win/

**Mac:**

```
$Java_HOME/include/linux/  --->  $Java_HOME/include/darwin/
```