# JavaCV giving java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, opencv, native, linker-errors

Alright, you may say "use google search for this, there are millions of them". However, I almost spent all day just to run following code but every since I tried I got **java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\jniopencv_core2477828805078034839.dll:
 Can't find dependent libraries** error which drives me mad.

I found **javacv-bin** folder which includes **javacpp.jar, javacv.jar, javacv-windows-x86.jar, javacv-windows-x86_64.jar**.

In Netbeans, I opened project properties and I added them into the libraries

I found **OpenCV2.3** folder, copied and pasted it into C:\ directory.

I added **C:\OpenCV2.3\build\bin; C:\OpenCV2.3\build\x86\vc10\bin; C:\OpenCV2.3\build\x64\vc10\bin;** in the **PATH.**

And I believe nothing to do left. However, every since I tried I got the same error. I'm exhausted please someone help me.

And last to say, I have both **32-bit** and **64-bit** JDKs so I tried both compilers but it's no use.

```
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.*;

public class Smoother {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        smooth("filename0.png");
    }
    public static void smooth(String filename) {
        System.out.println("java.library.path="+System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
        IplImage image = cvLoadImage(filename);
        if (image != null) {
            cvSmooth(image, image, CV_GAUSSIAN, 3);
            cvSaveImage(filename, image);
            cvReleaseImage(image);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at this [question thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441198/opencv-to-jni-how-to-make-it-work)?

Comment: Of course I did. He had the same problem and his question is also unsolved :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem as you did. Assuming your openCV folder location is `C:\OpenCV2.3`, here is what to do.

1. Create path and classpath variables under both user AND system environment variables.
2. Append this to all four variables(Assuming you have the latest version of openCV2.3): `C:\OpenCV2.3\build\bin;C:\OpenCV2.3\build\x64\mingw\bin;C:\OpenCV2.3\build\x64\vc9\bin;C:\OpenCV2.3\build\x64\vc10\bin;C:\OpenCV2.3\build\x86\mingw\bin;C:\OpenCV2.3\build\x86\vc9\bin;C:\OpenCV2.3\build\x86\vc10\bin;`

Hope it helps!
Aravind

Comment: Yes. At the end. Thanks so much Aravind. You're a lifesaver :D

Comment: I'm also having this problem but I don't understand what this answer is telling you do. Could someone explain this step by step? Thanks.

Comment: @vince88 simply said: he is adding the location of openCV to his %PATH% variable. I only had to add the path, which applies to my system(32bit, so 32bit lib and i chose vc10). And whenever you change your path variable, you have to restart eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Two Tips:

- You can't mix 64 and x86 libraries in the pathes!
- restart Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked with OpenCV ,but somehow I made my JNI code work.Have you generated the .dll or it comes with the package? And check this post ,it may Ohelp [JNI error while calling a C subroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645637/jni-error-while-calling-a-c-subroutine) ... One more suggestion try putting your dll in system32 folder and then load it manually using System.load(path/to/dll) method...Happy coding

Comment: I found all the dll files in javacv-windows-x86.jar package. I don't know how to generate dll files. I'm quite noob about these stuffs. I tried to do some stuffs in JNI and I failed too. I'll try `System.load()` method. I'll give you feedback.

Comment: it's not working. I tried to load all dll's with both `System.load()` and `System.loadLibrary()` but it's no use :(

Answer (score 0):

If anybody have this problem and updating system path and class path didn't solve, rename your OpenCv2.3.1 directory to "opencv". It did solve my problem.